# C program doesn't recognize '\n' in file exported from MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab, newline

I have a matrix `G` in MATLAB that I have printed into a text file using:

```
file = fopen('G.dat','w');
fprintf(file, [repmat('%f\t', 1, size(G, 2)) '\n'], G'); 
fclose(file);
```

The dimension of this matrix is 100 x 500. If I count rows and columns using awk, for instance, using

```
cat G.dat | awk '{print NF}END{print NR}'
```

I see that the dimensions correspond to the original one.

Now, I want to read this file, G.dat, from a C program that counts the columns of the first row just to understand the columns' dimension as in:

```
    while (!feof(file) && (fscanf(file, "%lf%c", &k, &c) == 2) ) {
        Ng++; 
        if (c == '\n') 
            break;
}
```

Unfortunately it gives me Ng = 50000 and it doesn't recognize any of the '\n'.
Instead, if I create the text file just by copying and pasting the data, it works. Can you explain me why? Thanks!

Comment: Use a binary editor/viewer to view what is different between the files.

Comment: Shouldn't the second if be inside the first one?. Also, [don't use `feof`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Compose some small test matrix and step through in debugger.

Comment: Yes, ok. I have changed the loop but it doesn't change the result.. I will try with small matrices..

Comment: might using`\r\n` solve your problem?

Comment: I get a warning: "comparison is always false due to limited range of data type" and it doesn't affect the output.

Comment: You can't compare a character to `\r\n` as it is two characters...

Comment: @Anna Post your solution as an answer and accept it instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code's approach is too fragile to "counts the columns of the first row just to understand the columns' dimension".  `fscanf(file, "%lf%c"...` is too susceptible to variant white-space delimiters and EOL to detect the `'\n'`.

Recommend explicitly examine white-space to determine width:

```
// return 0 on success, 1 on error
int GetWidth(FILE *file, size_t *width) {
  *width = 0;
  for (;;) {
    int ch;
    while (isspace(ch = fgetc(file))) {
      if (ch == '\n') return 0;
    }
    if (ch == EOF) return 0;
    ungetc(ch, file);
    double d;
    if (fscanf(file, "%lf", &d) != 1)) {
      return 1;  // unexpected non convertible text
    }
    (*width)++;
  }
}

//Sample, usage
size_t width;
if (GetWidth(file, &width)) return 1;

// read entire file
rewind(file);
for (size_t line = 0; foo(); line++)
  for (size_t column = 0; column<width; column++) {
    double d;
    if (fscanf(file, "%lf", &d) != 1)) {
      break;  // EOF, unexpected non convertible text or input error
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you working in Windows? Try opening your output file in text mode:

```
file = fopen('G.dat','wt');
```

This will automatically insert a carriage return before each newline when writing to the file.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the matlab syntax correctly, this expands to a format string like `%f\t%f\t%f\t\n\%f\t%f\t%f\t\n` for a 3x2 matrix. Note the extra `\t` at the end of each line. If this assumption is correct, the last `fscanf()` call in a line will assign the last `\t` to `&c`. The next `fscanf()` call just skips the `\n` because it doesn't match your format.

I'd propose you use `fgets()` instead for reading each line and then loop over the fields using `strtok()`, reading the values with `atof()` e.g.

```
char buf[8192];
if (fgets(buf, 8192, file))
{
    if (strtok(buf, '\t'))
    {
        ++Ng;
        while (strtok(0, '\t')) ++Ng;
    }
}
else
{
    /* error reading ... */
}
```

Comment: It is ok but vector "buf" needs a dimension and I often have to read matrix with columns of order from 1e2 to 1e6..

Comment: Well, in this case, read the file one character at a time, counting the `\t` characters until you hit a `\n` and use `malloc()` for the line buffer with a size `(Ng * (##maxlen(float)## +1) +2)`, the maxlen being the maximum length of a float in text representation...

Answer (score 0):

Matlab writes rows as

```
 %f\t%\f .. %f\t\n
```

which is a problem. I have used

```
dlmwrite('G.dat', G, '\t');
```

and it is fine!